# 12 string tuning to DADGAD

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings, 12-string-guitar

For tuning dadgad on my 12 string would it be:

D1D2 A1A2 etc up to gad (leaving gad same octave) on my tuner to get the correct octaves?

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are off by one, it would be D3 D2 etc. The note D1 is a step below the range of a bass in standard tuning.

Also, most 12 string guitars have the G (3rd) string in octaves, not unisons. One could modify their setup if they want the G in unison though.

Here is a diagram of the notes on a 12 string with standard tuning with the alternate notes you want written in:

[image]

FYI, some people would use an F# instead of a G so the guitar is tuned to a D chord (open D tuning) but I answered based exactly on what you asked for.

Comment: About your last comment: I often meet guitarists who play dadgad, but though I've heard about open D tuning I've never encountered it "in the wild". Then again I'm not a guitarist, so my point of reference might be narrow, but at least in some circles this is the case. The people I refer to mainly play Irish or Scandinavian traditional music.